# Does AkkaSystem.scheduler() and AkkaSystem.dispatcher() work as single thread?

Tags: java, thread-safety, akka, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on an Akka project and encountered code like this:

```
akkaScheduler.scheduleOnce(duration, () -> {
    // Access a map
}), dispatcher)
```

Here `akkaScheduler` assigned as `akkaSystem.scheduler()` and `dispatcher` is assigned as `akkaSystem.dispatcher()`.

Because there are many `scheduleOnce` and these Runnables may trigger in the same time, I wonder whether they will "Access a map" simultaneously from different thread? i.e. should I use a thread-safe map (like ConcurrentHashMap) here?

Comment: In the snippet of code you provided, where is `dispatcher` being passed? It's not an argument to `scheduleOnce`, so what is it?

Comment: Here is the **Java** code and just passes 3 arguments. According to akka doc https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/actor/Scheduler.html (we use akka 2.5), I find a method `def scheduleOnce(delay: Duration, runnable: Runnable)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Cancellable`. I don't know if `implicit executor` may be 3rd argument because I'm not familiar with scala.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading your snippet wrong, but you seem to have a misplaced `)`. In any case, the scheduler uses whatever implementation you've specific in the [Akka configuration](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/configuration-reference.html). The default seems to be a `LightArrayRevolverScheduler`. This seems to use a single thread to schedule tasks but then dispatches to the execution context provided, here that's your `dispatcher`. In the same configuration I linked, it shows how the dispatcher is configured to use a specific executor (which you can control).

Comment: We use something like internal-dispatcher ( type = Dispatcher,  executor = "fork-join-executor", fork-join-executor {parallelism-min = 4, parallelism-max = 8} ) . Does it means many runnable will be executed in different threads?

Comment: I believe so. But you can always verify by submitting a bunch of tasks that just print the current thread's id/name.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the particular dispatcher/executor/execution context, but in general, it's a safe assumption that multiple tasks could execute simultaneously on different threads.  Therefore, if scheduling tasks, it's important to ensure that they either don't care about concurrent mutation (e.g. they're idempotent) or that any mutations involve some means of synchronization to prevent concurrent mutation.

Using a thread-safe structure is one such way, however, the more Akka-idiomatic way would be to only expose the structure (which need not be thread-safe itself) through an actor and have the scheduled task only send messages to that actor.  While doing this is perhaps heavier-weight than using a `ConcurrentHashMap` (or whatever), it has a couple of significant benefits:

- It can become cluster-aware (e.g. by being a cluster singleton or by using distributed data) and/or persistent (via Akka Persistence)
- By exposing a richer domain-specifc/domain-meaningful protocol ("richer" meaning "rich enough that nothing (including a scheduled task) needs to send multiple messages"), you can get very firm transactional semantics